# SQL Subquery to count number of records based on difference between 2 dates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm querying a results set of patients who were admitted into hospital during the timeframe: 1st Jan 2016 - 31st Dec 2016, and who died.

As part of the results set, I need to include a column ('Number of Prior Admissions') that gives a total of any prior admissions the patient has had in the 12 month period up to the date of their final admission.

So, if a patient was admitted 1st June 2016 and died, and has 2 previous admissions on 1st July 2015 and 30th September 2015, the total would be '2' in this column.

The logic therefore needs to be: if patient was admitted on xx/xx/xxxx date and died, count the number of prior admissions for the same patient where the admission date is within 365 days from xx/xx/xxxx.

I've tried doing this as the following subquery, but get 2 issues:

1) the query appears to be counting all admissions records within the table, rather than just those relating to the individual patient.

2) the result is excluding any patients whose only attendance was their final one (i.e. they had no prior attendances). If they have no prior attendances, I want a 0 to appear in the column.

Please can anyone advise on the correct approach/syntax?

This is the sub query I've attempted:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
EP.Patient_Id
,EP.Admission_Date 'Final Admission Date'
,(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Inpatients.vw_IP_Episodes IP
    WHERE DATEDIFF(day,IP.Admission_Date,EP.Admission_Date) < '365'
    AND IP.Discharge_Method != 'Patient died'
 ) 
 AS 'No of Prior Admissions'

FROM Inpatients.vw_IP_Episodes EP
WHERE EP.Admission_Date BETWEEN '01/01/2016' AND '31/12/2016'
AND EP.Discharge_Method = 'Patient died'

GROUP BY EP.Patient_Id, EP.Admission_Date
```

Comment: I think your subquery should be also filtering on IP.Patient_Id = EP.Patient_Id - that should fix your issue #1.

Comment: You might also consider rewriting your WHERE statement to use a proper SARG for your date filtering. IP.Admission_Date >= DATEADD(day, -365, EP.Admission_Date). This will help the optimizer pick the correct indexes if you have any on the Admission_Date. Lastly, more business related if the discharge date and the admission date for the death are not the same, if the date of death is your concern you might switch to discharge date for EP.

Comment: Thank you @Anssssss. Actually, this fixes both issues, although it gives me a further problem. The returned result is doubling up some of the counts. I've modified the sub query SELECT to distinct on a primary key `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT IP.Inpatient_Episode_Primary_Key)` but this makes no difference.

Comment: Thank you @AnthonyHancock I've applied the optimised code to my query. Yes, it's a valid point on potential disparity between admission and discharge date. The focus of the report is around admission dates rather than the actual date of the death (even if it's several days later than the admission), so this is the reference point we've taken.

Comment: @Jon295087, not sure why the doubling would occur...perhaps you could debug the problem by looking into what rows the subquery is finding for a particular EP.Patient_Id and EP.Admission_Date value. Also, not a big deal, but I think the GROUP BY at the end is unnecessary (since you're not doing any aggregate functions in the main query - the COUNT(*) is in the subquery).

Comment: I think what you are seeing is that the final admission is still being included. If you have unique record IDs per discharge you could add to the WHERE in your subquery AND IP.DischargeID <> EP.DischargeID. Otherwise you can base it off of the date using AND IP.Admission_Date <> EP.Admission_Date. Not sure if your discharge data is better than ours but depending on how the PatientID is created this would count if any admissions happened after their death as well.

Comment: @Anthony, I don't think it would be finding rows where IP = EP since the IP.Discharch_Method != 'Patient died' and the EP.Discharge_Method = 'Patient died'. The admissions after death though...seems like the only possibility (though physically impossible). Bad data I guess. If the OP could dummy up some fake data to test with, the solution would probably be easy to find.

Comment: @Anssssss my concern would be how the PatientID is generated; and the scope of the OP's data set. I work with Hospital Discharge at a state level and there isn't a shared unique identifier across every hospital, we have to create the PatientID. This means you can have overmatching/undermatching where a PatientID is shared among more than one person or a single person has multiple IDs. Healthcare data is a nightmare and government data makes it worse.

Comment: @Anthony thanks for your further comments. I'll take another look when I'm back in the office on friday. The actual query I'm using (I've simplified this one slightly for discussion purposes) also has a left outer join in the main query to pull in some consultant fields. Maybe this is causing the issues, though in theory it shouldn't unless the consultant view has duplicates. It's definitely not pulling in the final admission, as I've already pulled the data out through 2 separate queries and verified the results. im just trying to build a single query as a learning exercise.

Comment: @AnthonyHancock. Cracked it. It wasn't the left join, it was where I was trying to DISTINCT on the Episode Primary Key. Obvious really (in my defence, only been working with NHS data for a month :-) ), but there's multiple episodes per spell, and it's the number of spell admissions that I'm trying to count. Unfortunately, there's no foreign key in the table for the spell (i'll be requesting that it's added), so instead I've distincted the sub query on the admission date, and that's reconciled my figures.

Comment: I guess there's a risk of error if someone presents and is admitted, then discharged, and then presents again on the same date, which I why I need to get the spell ID included in the view. Thanks again for your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to discussion with others, here's the solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
EP.Patient_Id
,EP.Admission_Date 'Final Admission Date'
,(
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT IP.Admission_Date)
    FROM Inpatients.vw_IP_Episodes IP
    WHERE IP.Admission_Date >= DATEADD(day, -365, EP.Admission_Date)
    AND IP.Patient_Id = EP.Patient_Id
    AND IP.Discharge_Method != 'Patient died'
 ) 
 AS 'No of Prior Admissions'

FROM Inpatients.vw_IP_Episodes EP
WHERE EP.Admission_Date BETWEEN '01/01/2016' AND '31/12/2016'
AND EP.Discharge_Method = 'Patient died'

GROUP BY EP.Patient_Id, EP.Admission_Date
```

Answer (score -1):

CTE maybe the best to remove duplicates.

```
;WITH cte AS(SELECT EP.Patient_Id
        ,EP.Admission_Date 'Final Admission Date'
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EP.Patient_Id ORDER BY EP.Admission_Date DESC) AS Rownum  
        , (SELECT  COUNT(*) AS [No of Prior Admissions]
                FROM Inpatients.vw_IP_Episodes IP
                WHERE Admission_Date >= DATEADD(day, -365, EP.Admission_Date)
                AND Admission_Date < EP.Admission_Date
                AND IP.Patient_Id = EP.Patient_Id
                ) [No of Prior Admissions]
    FROM Inpatients.vw_IP_Episodes EP
    WHERE EP.Admission_Date BETWEEN '01/01/2016' AND '31/12/2016'
    AND EP.Discharge_Method = 'Patient died'
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE Rownum = 1;
```

Comment: Hi @Wendy, I'm afraid that this doesn't run.

Comment: `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near ')'.`

Comment: I already edited query on the same day. It didn't work either?